# How to remove duplicated columns and last 5 rows from a Dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have 50 DataFrame , which is tab separated and has two columns. I need to add column name to these files.

Here is an example how the files looks like,

```
    ==> PE07_ID.count <==
ENSG00000000003 0
ENSG00000000005 0
ENSG00000000419 586
ENSG00000000457 97

==> PE07_REL.count <==
ENSG00000000003 2
ENSG00000000005 0
ENSG00000000419 954

==> PE08_ID.count <==
ENSG00000000003 0
ENSG00000000005 0
ENSG00000000419 317
```

And what I need is to add column name to each of these, I mean for the first column it can be named as "Gene" and the second column should be named after the file name

And here is what I tried so far,

First I called all files ,

```
 path       = '/user/home/files' 
files = os.listdir(path)

files_txt  = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in files if i.endswith('count')]

## Change it into dataframe
dfs_patty = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(x, sep='\t') for x in files_txt]
```

The files_txt looks like this,for 50 data frames

```
['/user/home/AE02_REL.count',
 '/user/home/AE04_REL.count',
 '/user/home/AE05_ID.count',
 '/user/home/AE05_REL.count'....]
```

And after this, I tried to add two header name or column names for the following

```
path       = '/home/user/dir/' 

file_names = []
data_frames = []

for filename in os.listdir(path): 
    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] 
    file_names.append(name) 
    df = pd.read_csv(path + filename, header=None,sep='\t') 
    df.rename(columns={1: name, 0:'Gene'}, inplace=True)
    #df.columns = ["Gene",filename]
    data_frames.append(df)
combined = pd.concat(data_frames, axis=1)
```

Then,

```
combined.head()

Gene    AE02_REL    Gene    AE04_REL    Gene    AE05_ID Gene    AE05_REL    Gene    AE07_REL    ... Gene    PL08_REL    Gene    PL09_ID Gene    PL09_REL    Gene    PL10_ID Gene    PL10_REL
0   ENSG00000000003 0   ENSG00000000003 1   ENSG00000000003 2   ENSG00000000003 16  ENSG00000000003 29  ... ENSG00000000003 2   ENSG00000000003 9   ENSG00000000003 1   ENSG00000000003 1   ENSG00000000003 4
5 rows × 100 columns
```

And When I try to remove the duplicated columns,
It's throwing following error,

```
    Columns_dup_droped =combined.drop_duplicates(cols=['Gene'])
    pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels (pandas/hashtable.c:13820)()

ValueError: Buffer has the wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

In the end, I need for each file something like this, for example,

```
==> PE07_ID.count <==
ENSG00000000003 0
ENSG00000000005 0
ENSG00000000419 586
ENSG00000000457 97
ENSG00000000460 44
ENSG00000001167 978
```

Should be,

```
Gene  PE07_ID.count
ENSG00000000003 0
ENSG00000000005 0
ENSG00000000419 586
ENSG00000000457 97
ENSG00000001167 978
```

Also, the tail of the Dataframe have rows starting with  "__" and I need to remove those last five lines,

I have tried the following,

```
combined.irow(slice(-5, None))
```

But Its just giving em last rows..Whereas I need to remove them from whole dataFrame

And so for all 50 DataFrames..

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You likely need to specify the full, absolute path of the files (which you strip out) rather than just the file name.  Otherwise Python will look for the files in the directory of the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a little change, I could get what I needed,
And I am posting what helped me here.

```
    path  = '/home/user/dir/out/' 

file_names = []
data_frames = []

for filename in os.listdir(path): 
    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] 
    file_names.append(name) 
    df = pd.read_csv(path + filename, header=None, sep='\t') 
    df = df.rename(columns={1: name, 0:'Gene'}).set_index('Gene')
    data_frames.append(df)
combined = pd.concat(data_frames, axis=1)
```

So as it you can see when we set index as 'Gene', then the same column is not repeating anymore

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment you need to reference the full path name.

If you change your path to:

```
path       = '/user/home/files/'
```

And your loop to:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    file_names.append(name)
    df = pd.read_csv(path + filename, header=None)
    df.columns = ["Gene",filename]
    data_frames.append(df)
```

It should work provided the data read into Dataframe has two columns.

Comment: Instead of `path + filename` you should use `os.path.join(path,filename)`

Comment: Hello Thanks for the solution .But could you please see about in my question the result should be the first column should be Gene and then the name of the file as the second column name.

Comment: for filename in os.listdir(path):
    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    file_names.append(name)
    df = pd.read_csv(path + filename, header=None,sep='\t')
    df.rename(columns={1: name, 0:'Gene'}, inplace=True)
    data_frames.append(df)

Comment: But this only working for one file not for all 50 files

Comment: Ok, so Now I have all teh 50 data frame, But it looks like this, Gene AE02_REL.count Gene AE04_REL.count Gene AE05_ID.count Gene AE05_REL.count Gene AE07_REL.count ... Gene PL08_REL.count Gene PL09_ID.count Gene PL09_REL.count Gene PL10_ID.count Gene PL10_REL.count
0 ENSG00000000003 0 ENSG00000000003 1 ENSG00000000003 2 ENSG00000000003 16

Comment: Like you see the Gene Column is repeated multiple times, whereas I only need it once

Comment: I have edited the primary question, now the issues are to remove the duplicated columns and last 5 rows of the Dataframe